# What technology to use for gather trends and analytics off multiple Crowd Funding sites

Tags: statistics, web-scraping, data-mining

Ive explored the idea of delivering trending content and important updates to a user base of people that are interested in crowd funded projects. I would like to somehow gather data of whats trending and certain analytic information so I could construct an overview of important information.

What would be the best technology to do this? I've read on Data Mining, Scraping...ect but not sure whats the most effective and cost efficient. Any other ideas for getting the data are much appreciated!

Comment: you'd better define what kind of resources (web sites, services) you are going to scrape from. Would you update your question?

Answer (score 0):

As far as `trending` research I'd recommend you to start off from the [Google Trends](https://webscraping.pro/google-trends-review/) and also get to know other [Google services for business analisys](https://webscraping.pro/google-services-for-business-analytics/).